# NSURLSession does not return

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, ios9, nsurlsession

Any idea why `NSURLSession` completion block isn't get called? With `NSURLConnection` it works, but `NSURLConnection` is deprecated in iOS 9.

```
let username = "8r6nibK8Pe28WFhjTX1gGb1Rhhhc7xM02v7XKRPedL4"
let password = "8r6nibK8Pe28WFhjTX1gGb1Rhhhc7xM02v7XKRPedL4"
let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

// create the request
let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?$format=json&Query='Rambo'+'Oscar'")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

let a = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()).dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, urlResponse, error in

    if data != nil {

        let str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(str)
    } else {
        _ = 7
    }  
})
```

Comment: Updated comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `a` is an NSURLSessionDataTask.

But you are only creating it. Once you have it you need to actually run it with:

```
a.resume()
```

Comment: Btw, do you know why printed message contains: `The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported`, I am using basic authentication. I would expect some meaningful response with image information.

Comment: Try adding the authorisation to the Configuration, not the request. For example: https://gist.github.com/n8armstrong/5c5c828f1b82b0315e24

Comment: tried, does not work, but created an other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907981/nsurlsession-returns-different-response-than-browser-would-why